# Show that $SL_2(F_3)/Z(SL_2(F_3)) \cong A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof, group-isomorphism, sylow-theory

Show that $SL_2(F_3)/Z(SL_2(F_3)) \cong A_4$

I know that $|SL_2(F_3)/Z(SL_2(F_3))|= 12$.

Then if the quotient group has a normal subgroup of order $4$ then it is isomorphic to $A_4$.

Suppose that it has a normal subgroup of order $3$ then we need to find a contradiction.

Suppose that $V$ is the normal subgroup of order $3$ in $SL_2(F_3)/Z(SL_2(F_3))$ then $V$ is a normal subgroup of order $6$ in $SL_2(F_3)$. Also we see that $V$ must be congruent to $S_3$.

Then how do we proceed after this? Is there a way to proceed from here. There is another answer on the site, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1325327/104041), which doesn't seem intuitive to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325327/sl-2-mathbb-z-3-zsl-2-mathbb-z-3-cong-a-4?rq=1)

Comment: I was looking for a different approach to the problem

Comment: See [groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/PSL(2,3)_is_isomorphic_to_A4), and also the notes of [Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/group12.pdf), where the argument is that  $PSL(2,\Bbb F_3)\cong A_4$, because $n_3>1$. This is proved in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089825/a-group-of-order-12-either-has-a-normal-3-sylow-subgroup-or-is-isomorphic-t).

Answer (score 1):

$PSL_2(\Bbb F_3)$ has more than one Sylow $3$-subgroup so that it must be isomorphic to $A_4$ - see the following post:

[A group of order $12$ either has a normal $ 3$-Sylow subgroup or is isomorphic to $A_4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089825/a-group-of-order-12-either-has-a-normal-3-sylow-subgroup-or-is-isomorphic-t)

Comment: I just wanted to ask is there a way to find all the $4$ sylow $3$ subgroups of $SL_2(F_3)$.I was looking for this but I got only $2$ sylow subgroups. How do I find the rest.Is there any linear algebra trick to find it ?

Comment: You can find the $3$-Sylow subgroups at this site, too. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3927436/how-to-find-sylow-3-subgroups-of-sl-nf-3?rq=1) and try more conjugations as Hagen says. Of course, it is enough to show that there is more than $1$, which you have done already.